# CUDF error processing a large number of parquet files

Tags: python, nvidia, dask, parquet, cudf

I have 2000 parquet files in a directory. Each parquet file is roughly 20MB in size. The compression used is SNAPPY. Each parquet file has rows that look like the following:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------------+
| customerId | productId | randomAttribute |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+
| ID1        | PRODUCT1  | ATTRIBUTE1      |
| ID2        | PRODUCT2  | ATTRIBUTE2      |
| ID2        | PRODUCT3  | ATTRIBUTE3      |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Each column entry is a string.
I am using p3.8xlarge EC2 instance with the following configurations:

- **RAM**: 244GB
- **vCPU**: 32
- **GPU RAM**: 64GB (each GPU core has 16GB of RAM)
- **GPUs**: 4 Tesla V100

I am trying the following code:

```py
def read_all_views(parquet_file_lst):
    df_lst = []    
    for file in parquet_file_lst:
        df = cudf.read_parquet(file, columns=['customerId', 'productId'])
        df_lst.append(df)
    return cudf.concat(df_lst)
```

This crashes after processing the first 180 files with the following runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 9, in read_all_views
File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cudf/io/parquet.py", line 54, in read_parquet
    use_pandas_metadata,
File "cudf/_lib/parquet.pyx", line 25, in 
cudf._lib.parquet.read_parquet
File "cudf/_lib/parquet.pyx", line 80, in cudf._lib.parquet.read_parquet
RuntimeError: rmm_allocator::allocate(): RMM_ALLOC: unspecified launch failure
```

Only 10% of both GPU and the CPU RAM is utilized at any given time.
Any ideas how to debug this or what are the workarounds for the same?

Comment: Have you tried to read all files with `dask`? See [this](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/gpu.html)

Comment: I have now. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

cuDF is a single GPU library. 2000 files of 20 MB would be about 40 GB of data, which is more than you can fit in memory in a single V100 GPU.

For workflows that require more a single GPU, cuDF relies on Dask. The following example illustrates how you could use cuDF + Dask to read data into distributed GPU memory with multiple GPUs in a single node. This doesn't answer your debugging question, but should hopefully solve your problem.

First, I use a few lines of code to create a Dask cluster of two GPUs.

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
import dask_cudf

cluster = LocalCUDACluster() # by default use all GPUs in the node. I have two.
client = Client(cluster)
client
# The print output of client:
# 
# Client
# Scheduler: tcp://127.0.0.1:44764
# Dashboard: http://127.0.0.1:8787/status

# Cluster
# Workers: 2
# Cores: 2
# Memory: 404.27 GB
```

Next I'll create a couple of parquet files for this example.

```py
import os

import cudf
from cudf.datasets import randomdata

if not os.path.exists('example_output'):
    os.mkdir('example_output')

for x in range(2):
    df = randomdata(nrows=10000,
                dtypes={'a':int, 'b':str, 'c':str, 'd':int},
                seed=12)
    df.to_parquet('example_output/df')
```

Let's look at the memory on each of my GPUs with `nvidia-smi`.

```
nvidia-smi
Thu Sep 26 19:13:46 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.104      Driver Version: 410.104      CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   51C    P0    29W /  70W |   6836MiB / 15079MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:D8:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   47C    P0    28W /  70W |   5750MiB / 15079MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice the two values. 6836 MB on GPU 0 and 5750 MB on GPU 1 (I happen to have unrelated data already in memory on these GPUs). Now let's read our entire directory of two parquet files with Dask cuDF and then `persist` it. Persisting it forces computation -- Dask execution is lazy so just calling `read_parquet` only adds a task to the task graph. `ddf` is a Dask DataFrame.

```py
ddf = dask_cudf.read_parquet('example_output/df')
ddf = ddf.persist()
```

Now let's look at `nvidia-smi` again.

```
Thu Sep 26 19:13:52 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.104      Driver Version: 410.104      CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   51C    P0    29W /  70W |   6938MiB / 15079MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:D8:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   47C    P0    28W /  70W |   5852MiB / 15079MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Dask handles distributing our data across both GPUs for us.