# MemoryError: std::bad_alloc: rapids.ai Dask-cuDF

Tags: python, pandas, dask, rapids, cudf

I would like to load 5.9 GB CSV and I don't use pandas library. I have 4 GPUs. I use [rapids.ai](https://rapids.ai) to load this large dataset faster but every time that I tried, this error is shown to me although I have space in my other GPU memory. memory usage of GPUs at the beginning are:

```
GPU 0
total    : 11554717696
free     : 11126046720
used     : 428670976
GPU 1
total    : 11554717696
free     : 11542331392
used     : 12386304
GPU 2
total    : 11554717696
free     : 11542331392
used     : 12386304
GPU 3
total    : 11551440896
free     : 11113070592
used     : 438370304
```

and the code is:

```py
import cudf
import pandas as pd
import time
import subprocess as sp
import os
import dask_cudf

name = 'T100'
path = '/media/mo/2438a3d1-29fe-4c6f-aafb-f906acd5140d/AIMD/c1/trajs/'+name+'.CSV'
start = time.time()


data = dask_cudf.from_cudf(cudf.read_csv(path),
                         npartitions=4).compute()
done = time.time()
elapsed = done - start
print(elapsed)
```

the prompt:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1fff5fb4e9b4> in <module>
      2 
      3 
----> 4 data = dask_cudf.from_cudf(cudf.read_csv(path),
      5                          npartitions=4).compute()
      6 done = time.time()

~/anaconda3/envs/machineLearning/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py in inner(*args, **kwds)
     72         def inner(*args, **kwds):
     73             with self._recreate_cm():
---> 74                 return func(*args, **kwds)
     75         return inner
     76 

~/anaconda3/envs/machineLearning/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cudf/io/csv.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, header, mangle_dupe_cols, usecols, sep, delimiter, delim_whitespace, skipinitialspace, names, dtype, skipfooter, skiprows, dayfirst, compression, thousands, decimal, true_values, false_values, nrows, byte_range, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, comment, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, prefix, index_col, **kwargs)
     82         na_filter=na_filter,
     83         prefix=prefix,
---> 84         index_col=index_col,
     85     )
     86 

cudf/_lib/csv.pyx in cudf._lib.csv.read_csv()

MemoryError: std::bad_alloc: CUDA error at: /conda/conda-bld/librmm_1591196551527/work/include/rmm/mr/device/cuda_memory_resource.hpp66: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation out of memory
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question :[CUDF error processing a large number of parquet files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114113/cudf-error-processing-a-large-number-of-parquet-files)

explains how to use dask_cudf to read large files : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58123478/13887495

Following the instruction provided in the answer should help you solve `MemoryError: std::bad_alloc: CUDA error at: /conda/conda-bld/librmm_1591196551527/work/include/rmm/mr/device/cuda_memory_resource.hpp66: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation out of memory`

Answer (score 0):

the code should be

```py
data = dask_cudf.read_csv(path,
                         npartitions=4)
```