# Cudf only using single gpu to load data

Tags: python, pandas, nvidia, cudf

I have a large file that I want to load using cudf.read_csv().  The file in question is too large to fit in a single gpu's memory, but still small enough to fit into cpu memory.  I can load the file by pd.read_csv(), but it takes forever!  In smaller (but still quite large) files, cudf.read_csv() is around 6-10x faster than pandas.

When using cudf.read_csv(), I notice that only 1 out of the 4 Tesla V100-DGXS available actually loads data.  The rest sit idle.  I image if all 4 were used, the file would fit into memory.  How can I use all 4 gpu to load the file?

Note:  I know I can use a hack like cudf.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=FIRST_n_COLS) and sequentially load batches of columns.  While this would fit into memory, I would prefer a more elegant solution if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple GPUs, and want to use all of them at once, please use `dask_cudf`.  [RAPIDS has a few guides for this](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/10min.html), but @Nick Becker did a great job explaining it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58123478/1309051.  That will get you on your way

Comment: Thanks for the reference!  That was what I was looking for.