# Unable to load and compute dask_cudf dataframe into blazing table and seeing some memory related errors. (cudaErrorMemoryAllocation out of memory)

Tags: python, memory, dask, dask-distributed, rapids

**Issue :**

Trying to load a file (CSV and Parquet) using Dask CUDF and seeing some memory related errors. The dataset can easily fit into memory and the file
can be read correctly using BlazingSQL's read_parquet method. However the dask_cudf.read_parquet() method fails to do the same.
Seeing the same error with both file formats.

Other observation is that when a blazingSQL table is created from cudf dataframe , the table gets created but with zero records.

It will be helpful if someone can give any pointers to get over this issue.

**Dataset info:**

No of rows - 126 Million
No of colums - 209
File Format – parquet
No of Partitions - 8
File size parquet - 400 MB
File size csv - 62 GB

**System info :**

GPU - 6  ( V100 TESLA)
Memory - 16GB GPU
Cores - 32 Cores

**Client info:**
Scheduler: tcp://127.0.0.1:36617
Dashboard: http://127.0.0.1:8787/status
Cluster
Workers: 4
Cores: 4
Memory: 239.89 GiB

**Code :**

```
from blazingsql import BlazingContext
from dask.distributed import Client,wait
from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
import dask
import dask_cudf
cluster = LocalCUDACluster()
client = Client(cluster)
bc = BlazingContext(dask_client=client)


ddf = dask_cudf.read_parquet('/home/ubuntu/126M_dataset/')
bc.create_table('table', ddf.compute())
```

**Error Message:**

```
super(NumericalColumn, col).fillna(fill_value, method)
    501 
    502     def find_first_value(

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cudf/core/column/column.py in fillna(self, value, method, dtype)
    733         """
    734         return libcudf.replace.replace_nulls(
--> 735             input_col=self, replacement=value, method=method, dtype=dtype
    736         )
    737 

cudf/_lib/replace.pyx in cudf._lib.replace.replace_nulls()

cudf/_lib/scalar.pyx in cudf._lib.scalar.as_device_scalar()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cudf/core/scalar.py in device_value(self)
     75         if self._device_value is None:
     76             self._device_value = DeviceScalar(
---> 77                 self._host_value, self._host_dtype
     78             )
     79         return self._device_value

cudf/_lib/scalar.pyx in cudf._lib.scalar.DeviceScalar.__init__()

cudf/_lib/scalar.pyx in cudf._lib.scalar.DeviceScalar._set_value()

cudf/_lib/scalar.pyx in cudf._lib.scalar._set_numeric_from_np_scalar()

MemoryError: std::bad_alloc: CUDA error at: /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/include/rmm/mr/device/cuda_memory_resource.hpp:69: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation out of memory
```

**System Info :**

**nvidia-smi info:**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.19.01    Driver Version: 465.19.01    CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA Tesla V1...  On   | 00000000:00:1B.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   49C    P0    55W / 300W |  16147MiB / 16160MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA Tesla V1...  On   | 00000000:00:1C.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   48C    P0    56W / 300W |  16106MiB / 16160MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA Tesla V1...  On   | 00000000:00:1D.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   46C    P0    61W / 300W |  16106MiB / 16160MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA Tesla V1...  On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   48C    P0    60W / 300W |  16106MiB / 16160MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A    113949      C   ...ntu/miniconda3/bin/python      823MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    114055      C   ...ntu/miniconda3/bin/python    15319MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A    114059      C   ...ntu/miniconda3/bin/python    16101MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A    114062      C   ...ntu/miniconda3/bin/python    16101MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A    114053      C   ...ntu/miniconda3/bin/python    16101MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

> File size parquet - 400 MB File size csv - 62 GB
> GPU - 6 ( V100 TESLA) Memory - 16GB GPU Cores - 32 Cores

When you call `compute` on a Dask collection, it fully computes the result and brings it into the Client process as a single-GPU object. Your data is likely overwhelming the 16GB of memory on one of your GPUs. You are likely looking for `persist`, which fully computes the result and stores it in memory on the workers (note that the execution will happen in the background and `persist` will return quickly).

Additionally, you also shouldn't need to persist your data before creating a BlazingSQL table from a Dask object.

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114113/cudf-error-processing-a-large-number-of-parquet-files/58123478#58123478), [this blog post](https://medium.com/rapids-ai/reading-larger-than-memory-csvs-with-rapids-and-dask-e6e27dfa6c0f), and [this documentation](https://docs.blazingdb.com/docs/gpu-dataframe-gdf) useful.